# compilation error using STACK_OF(X509) in openssl version 1.0.2

Tags: c++, openssl

I have a method declared in .h file as

```
checktrustedCA(stack_st *)
```

And in .cpp file its defined as

```
checktrustedCA(STACK_OF(X509) *certificate)
{
...he
}
```

When i compile the program, it compiles fine in version 0.9.8 but gives error in version 1.0.2 - It says no overloaded function present with the signature `checktrustedCA(stack_st_x509*)` in the corresponding .h 
whereas it gives no error at all in version 0.9.8

Was anythng changed with respect to this in new openssl function?

Comment: Why are you declaring them differently?

Comment: I have no clue..Its a maintenance code which we have to update to use openssl 1.0.2